# ¿Como dar privilegios a un usuario para ejecutar todos los procedimientos?

Tags: mysql, sql

En Mysql como puedo dar permisos para que un usuario pueda ejecutar todos los procedimientos, he encontrado:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE miBD.miProcedure TO 'USER'@'localhost';
```

Como se ve solo puedes dar permiso a un procedimiento pero no a todos, como lograr dar permiso a todos sin hacerlo uno por uno. He probado:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE miBD.* TO 'USER'@'localhost';
```

Este query marca error. Y:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON miBD.* TO 'USER'@'localhost';
```

Este no los otorga.

Comment: Este caso lo resuelvo dando permisos a la base de datos mysql con el privilegio de select, no se si será una buena practica o segura de hacerlo pero me resuelve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un proyecto nos encontramos esta misma casuística. 
No conseguimos una manera directa de hacerlo en base a la documentación de MySQL.

Optamos por crear una query que "generase" una lista de comandos grant para todos los procedimientos de esta manera:

```
select concat('grant execute on procedure miBD.',name,' to user \'USER\'@\'localhost\';') from mysql.proc where db = 'miBD'
```

No es una manera directa ni muy limpia, pero al menos nos solucionó el tener que generar a mano todos los GRANTs.

Answer (score 1):

Sé que ya hace mucho de esta pregunta, pero yo descubrí este comando que le da permisos de todos los procedimientos a un usuario

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Este código le da permisos de todos los procedimientos al usuario indicado. Espero haber aportado algo.

Answer (score 0):

Una aportación mas, hay que quitar la palabra user después del 'to' y se puede concatenar el nombre de la base de datos por la que se filtra para hacer un poco dinámica la consulta

```
select concat('grant execute on procedure ',db,'.',name,' to \'USER\'@\'localhost\';') from mysql.proc where db = 'your_db_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'usuario'@'%';
```